# setting buildpack for heroku deployment using git strategy

Tags: heroku, deployment, travis-ci

travis has a config to [set the buildpack source](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/#Deploy-Strategy) for heroku deployment using the Anvil deploy strategy, but it doesn't specify how to set that config value using the git deploy strategy.

how do you set buildpack config value as a heroku config variable before deployment if you're using the git deployment strategy in travis?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For git deploys, Heroku relies on the [`BUILDPACK_URL` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack) to be configured for your repository.

Anvil doesn't utilize these settings, hence it needs to be manually specified in the deployment settings.